# Generate Code Quality Report from Sonar Lint

Tags: eclipse, sonarlint

I have a java code monitored by SonarLint written in Eclipse. I need to generate report from Sonar , does anyone know how to do this ?

Thanks

Comment: https://www.sonarlint.org/eclipse/howto.html ?

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend you to use `SonarQube` which is easier to create analysis reports as a PDF form, an excel report, or an html formatted report.

But if you need it in `eclispe` and `SonarLint`.

Right Click On Project ->

[image]

This will generate simple SonarLint Report.

Answer (score -3):

Sonarlint is aimed at helping developers to clean code and follow conventionally right coding practices. It is not aimed at report generation.

If you need you may try SonarQube

Comment: That is exactly what the other two answers are saying. Please don't add redundant answers on old questions, instead answer questions that don't have answers yet, or add answers that add new information not yet posted.